# Linux Command to Remove some Parts of text from html file

Tags: html, linux, find, command

I have more than 50k .`html` files on my server which were copied from another site.
Now I want to remove a portion of text from all the `.html` files using the Linux command line.

**Note**:

The portion of text I want to remove is not 100% the same, but similar to each other as shown in the code below. I want to save the text within the `@@` symbols. (The symbol @ is not present in the original files, I wrote it to highlight the portion which should be saved.)

```
Some Part of HTML Codes here

<br /></div>
@@
<h1> A Memorable Night </h1>
<p>
.......the text START here which I don't want to remove
.some text......
.......the text END here which I don't want to remove.
</p>
@@
Some Part of HTML Codes here
```

**Below is Full Code**

```
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN""http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> A Memorable Night  free download :: LipWap.Com </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="LipWap.Com  &gt; Stories &gt; Grate Male &gt; _A_Memorable_Night.txt"/>
<meta name="keywords" content=",Stories,Grate Male,_A_Memorable_Night.txt"/>
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<meta name="language" content="en" />
<link href="http://s4.LipWap.Com/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="logo">
<a href="http://LipWap.Com"><ge alt="LipWap.Com" src="/logo.gif" width="220" hight="42"/></a></div>      </div>

</div>
<div id="mainDiv">
<div class="ad1 tCenter p5">
<a href="http://click.buzzcity.net/click.php?partnerid=88888">
<ige sra="http://ads.buzzcity.net/show.php?partnerid=88888&get=mweb" alt="" />
</a>
<br /><br />
<a href="http://click.buzzcity.net/click.php?partnerid=88888">
<ige sra="http://ads.buzzcity.net/show.php?partnerid=88888&get=mweb" alt="" />          </a>
<br /></div>

@@
<h1> A Memorable Night </h1>
<p>
.......the text START here which i dnt want to remove
.some text......
.......the text END here which i dnt want to remove.
</p>
@@
</div><div class="randomFile">
<h3>Related Files</h3>

<!-- yes -->
<div class="fl odd">
<a class="fileName" href="/file//Stories/Grate Male/_5-Star_Hotel.txt.html"><div><div><ige sra="/prv//Stories/Grate Male/_5-Star_Hotel.txt.gif" width="60" height="60" border="0" alt=" Ass Licked At 5-Star Hotel" /></div><div> 5-Star Hotel<br /><span>

[2326&nbsp;Words]<br />76 hits</span></div></div></a>  </div>
<!-- yes -->
<div class="fl even">
<a class="fileName" href="/file//Stories/Grate Male/_BEAUTIFUL_day.txt.html"><div><div><ige sra="/prv//Stories/Grate Male/_BEAUTIFUL_day.txt.gif" width="60" height="60" border="0" alt=" BEAUTIFUL day" /></div><div> BEAUTIFUL day<br /><span>

[4279&nbsp;Words]<br />114 hits</span></div></div></a>  </div>
<!-- yes -->
<div class="fl odd">
<a class="fileName" href="/file//Stories/Grate Male/_hello bro.txt.html"><div><div><ige sra="/prv//Stories/Grate Male/_hello bro.txt.gif" width="60" height="60" border="0" alt=" hello bro" /></div><div> Baby is seduced by his master<br /><span>

[2102&nbsp;Words]<br />177 hits</span></div></div></a>  </div>


<div class="tCenter p5">
<a href="http://click.buzzcity.net/click.php?partnerid=88888">
<ige sra="http://ads.buzzcity.net/show.php?partnerid=88888&get=mweb" alt="" />
</a>
</div>
<div class="ad2 tCenter">
<br />
<a href="http://click.buzzcity.net/click.php?partnerid=88888">
<ige sra="http://ads.buzzcity.net/show.php?partnerid=88888&get=mweb" alt="" />          </a>
<br /></div>

<div class="l1"><a href="http://LipWap.Com/file//Stories/Grate%20Male/_Acceptance.txt.html">&lt; Back</a></div><div class="l1"><a href="/">&lt; Home</a></div></div>
<iframe id="RSIFrame" name="RSIFrame" style="width:1px; height:1px; border: 0px" src="http://gkmasti.com/newdata/cat//us/sort/time/page/0.html"></iframe>


     </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://daylogs.com/dw.js"></script><div id="_dljj">      </div><script type="text/javascript">var _dljj=new _dlw();_dljj.show('small','lipwap','jj');</script>

<!-- Start of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var sc_project=8352917;
var sc_invisible=1;
var sc_security="c57354d1";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js"></script>
<noscript><div class="statcounter"><a title="free hit
counters" href="http://statcounter.com/"
target="_blank"><ige class="statcounter"
sra="http://c.statcounter.com/8352917/0/c57354d1/1/"
alt="free hit counters"></a></div></noscript>
<!-- End of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->
<!----end--->`
```

Comment: Need to clarify a bit. Are you trying to get the text that is inside all the HTML? Is it "after the last opening tag and before the first closing tag? You need to be very specific about the characteristics of the text that tell you what to keep and what to discard. Most HTML files have a complex nested structure... Can you describe it more precisely?

Comment: I have just formatted your question a little bit - it now looks like you want everything from the `<h1>` opening tag through everything in the following `<p>...</p>` tags. Is that correct?

Comment: yaa its correct, but there is more <p>...</p> tags inside them

Comment: So how do you know when to stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command will do it :

```
awk 'BEGIN { echo = 0}
     /<h1>/{ echo = 1} 
     /<\/p>/{ echo = 0 } 
     {if (echo == 1) { print }}' *.html
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'BEGIN { echo = 0}                   # initially set the variable echo to zero
     /<h1>/{ echo = 1}                   # when you come across the pattern <h1>, set echo = 1
     /<\/p>/{ echo = 0 }                 # when you come across pattern </p> set echo = 0 
     {if (echo == 1) { print }}' *.html  # if echo is set to 1, print the line; 
                                         # do this for all .html files
```

Comment: i hv edited  post by adding the full code, u can chek now,,,,,,, thanks in advanced

Comment: Sorry - but it's still not completely clear. You need to describe very precisely **what is unique about the text that follows the text you want to keep**. Right now the first thing I see is a `</div>`. Is that in fact a unique separator? Or is it the presence of the word `randomFile`? I really can't guess... you have to supply the pattern. Right now in my code above, that pattern is `</p>`, which shows up (escaped and enclosed in slashes) as `/<\/p>/`. Whatever signals "end of text" should go in that line.

Comment: i want to keep only the part of text inside @@,,,,,,,, That is    @@<h1> A Memorable Night </h1>
<p>
.......the text START here which i dnt want to remove
.some text......
.......the text END here which i dnt want to remove.
</p>
@@`

Comment: You said there are no `@@` in your file... Do you understand what I am asking, and why I am asking it? Have you tried experimenting with my solution? If it doesn't do what you want please edit your question with "when I try Floris' answer _this_ happens with a file containing _this_, and I need the result to be _ that_". The idea of SO is that you (the asker) do most of the work.

Comment: sorry to be inactive for a long time.... now i will active here untill i get the solution.....

Comment: Welcome back! I think it is clear where you want the **start** of the text to be; but you need to come up with a good description of the *end** (for example: "it is the `</p>` just before the `<div>` of class `randomFile`" - a description that can be translated into a computer instruction).